# MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.14

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 required version 3.2.4. Otherwise is pip3 install mariadb inpossible:

```
$ pip3 install mariadb
>Collecting mariadb
  Using cached mariadb-1.1.1.zip (82 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2:
     command: /home/ben/miniconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xgo4i_hp/mariadb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xgo4i_hp/mariadb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-g1jirt2p
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xgo4i_hp/mariadb/
    Complete output (1 lines):
    MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.14
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest Version 3.2.4 direct from the webpage

https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/

you can also chekc if you have the right repository for mariadb https://mariadb.com/docs/clients/mariadb-connectors/connector-c/install/

Answer (score 1):

By mistake I've uploaded MariaDB Connector/Python 1.1 alpha to pypi.org with wrong versioning scheme, so a simple `pip3 install mariadb` installed 1.1.0-alpha instead of latest stable (which is 1.0.7).

This is fixed now, alpha will be installed only when you specify --pre.

For testing alpha you will need Connector/C 2.3.4 - which is quite new and likely not available yet on all distributions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix. It works with Ubuntu 20.04 now successfully.