# Pip install mariadb mac

Tags: python, mariadb, homebrew, mariadb-connector-c

I'm wanting to connect to a MariaDB database for a web app via Python but can't seem to install the `mariadb` package. I am running Mac with Python 3.7.9. Here is what I get when I try to run `pip install mariadb` is:

```
Collecting mariadb
  Using cached mariadb-1.0.11.zip (85 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for mariadb, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mariadb
    Running setup.py install for mariadb ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/.../bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/yz/_pkhkb0x2xb233lq1n0v193r0000gp/T/pip-install-yeefaepy/mariadb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/yz/_pkhkb0x2xb233lq1n0v193r0000gp/T/pip-install-yeefaepy/mariadb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/yz/_pkhkb0x2xb233lq1n0v193r0000gp/T/pip-record-ock6ntv0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/.../include/site/python3.7/mariadb
         cwd: /private/var/folders/yz/_pkhkb0x2xb233lq1n0v193r0000gp/T/pip-install-yeefaepy/mariadb/
    Complete output (46 lines):
    10.6.8
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb
    copying mariadb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb/constants
    copying mariadb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb/constants
    copying mariadb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb/constants
    copying mariadb/constants/INDICATOR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb/constants
    copying mariadb/constants/CURSOR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb/constants
    copying mariadb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'mariadb._mariadb' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/.../include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/MitchPudill/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DPY_MARIADB_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPY_MARIADB_MINOR_VERSION=0 -DPY_MARIADB_PATCH_VERSION=11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb-connector-c/3.3.1/include/mariadb -I/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb-connector-c/3.3.1/include/mariadb/mysql -I./include -I/Users/.../include -I/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/include/python3.7m -c mariadb/mariadb.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/mariadb/mariadb.o -DDEFAULT_PLUGINS_SUBDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb-connector-c/3.3.1/lib/mariadb/plugin"
    In file included from mariadb/mariadb.c:21:
    ./include/mariadb_python.h:75:2: error: Minimum required version of MariaDB Connector/C is 3.1.3
    #error Minimum required version of MariaDB Connector/C is 3.1.3
     ^
    ./include/mariadb_python.h:244:30: error: field has incomplete type 'enum enum_indicator_type'
        enum enum_indicator_type indicator;
                                 ^
    ./include/mariadb_python.h:244:10: note: forward declaration of 'enum enum_indicator_type'
        enum enum_indicator_type indicator;
             ^
    ./include/mariadb_python.h:297:5: error: unknown type name 'ps_field_fetch_func'
        ps_field_fetch_func func;
        ^
    mariadb/mariadb.c:273:45: error: use of undeclared identifier 'STMT_INDICATOR_NULL'
                           MrdbIndicator_Object(STMT_INDICATOR_NULL));
                                                ^
    mariadb/mariadb.c:275:45: error: use of undeclared identifier 'STMT_INDICATOR_DEFAULT'
                           MrdbIndicator_Object(STMT_INDICATOR_DEFAULT));
                                                ^
    mariadb/mariadb.c:277:45: error: use of undeclared identifier 'STMT_INDICATOR_IGNORE'
                           MrdbIndicator_Object(STMT_INDICATOR_IGNORE));
                                                ^
    mariadb/mariadb.c:279:45: error: use of undeclared identifier 'STMT_INDICATOR_IGNORE_ROW'
                           MrdbIndicator_Object(STMT_INDICATOR_IGNORE_ROW));
                                                ^
    7 errors generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/.../bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/yz/_pkhkb0x2xb233lq1n0v193r0000gp/T/pip-install-yeefaepy/mariadb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/yz/_pkhkb0x2xb233lq1n0v193r0000gp/T/pip-install-yeefaepy/mariadb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/yz/_pkhkb0x2xb233lq1n0v193r0000gp/T/pip-record-ock6ntv0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/.../include/site/python3.7/mariadb Check the logs for full command output.
```

What I've tried:

1. New virtual environment (same issue)
2. Different Python version (same issue)
3. `brew install mariadb-connector-c` (`mariadb-connector-c 3.3.1 is already installed and up-to-date`)
4. `brew install libmariadb-dev` & `brew install libmariadb3` (`No available formula with the name "libmariadb-dev"` & `No available formula with the name "libmariadb3"`)
5. `brew install mariadb`: installs but doesn't fix issue
6. Installing different but still relatively recent versions of `mariadb`: can do it but doesn't fix issue
7. Unlinking `mariadb` and linking `mariadb-connector-c`: can do it but doesn't fix issue

I've probably tried a few more things somewhere along the rabbit hole. Any suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONPY-85

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897310/mariadb-connector-python-requires-mariadb-connector-c-3-2-4-found-version-3)

Comment: @drum No, these users' errors occurred because they had an old version of `mariadb-connector-c`. As mentioned, my version of `mariadb-connector-c` is up to date.

Comment: Do you have have XCode CommandLine Tools installed? You can check with `xcode-select -p` and will get an error if not.

Comment: Your macOS is rather old too...

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, I have xcode (snippet returned `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`). My Mac is 2 years old.

Comment: I would try removing all the temporary links you have made, and all the related homebrew packages and then running `brew doctor` to see if there are any problems. Fix them and try installing again.

Answer (score 0):

If your XCode Command Line is out of date, it doesn't matter if you relink the mariadb connector-c or not. I couldn't make it work with:
python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 or the latest 3.10 versions. [just for the record, I use pyenv to support several python versions on my installation]

Going to AppStore and doing upgrade on XCode fixed the issue. After that, successfully installed:

```
pip install mariadb
```

into all of the above python versions with no issues at all.
Interesting that I couldn't find any recommendation in MariaDB documentaion/requirements. What exactly prevented the pip installation, I still don't know.

Hopefully this will help someone to avoid some headache.

Answer (score 0):

for me installing connector
`brew install mariadb-connector-c`

solves this issue