# Installing MariaDB in Dockercontainer - requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.16

Tags: docker, mariadb

I try to Build following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10
ENV TZ Europa/Berlin

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# install selenium
RUN pip install selenium

# install mariadb
RUN apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev
RUN pip install mariadb
```

But i am not able to install mariadb, instead i receive following error:

```
"MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.16"
```

What can i do to solve this Problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897310/mariadb-connector-python-requires-mariadb-connector-c-3-2-4-found-version-3)

Comment: Sadly not... I already use the Libs and with pip3 i get the same error massage.

Comment: I had to pin mariadb=1.05 to get mine to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MariaDB-10.5.15 version of libmariadb-dev corresponds to libmariadb-3.1.16.

Constrain `the pip install mariadb` to a [1.0 version](https://pypi.org/project/mariadb/1.0.11/#history).

Alternately use a Debian bullseye (that corresponds the python base image) libmariadb-dev from [the MariaDB Corporation repository](https://mariadb.com/docs/connect/programming-languages/c/install/#connector-c-install-repo-install).