# Mariadb in Docker: MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.16

Tags: python, docker, mariadb

I try the following Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
RUN apt install gcc libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev libmariadb-dev-compat -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install Flask Flask-SQLAlchemy flask-marshmallow marshmallow-sqlalchemy
RUN pip install mariadb==1.0.0
COPY ./back .
CMD [ "python3", "app.py"]
```

I get this error:
`MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.16`

And when I try with mariadb==1.0.0 I get this error:
`MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.1.3, found version 3.1.16`

I see the answer to this post [Installing MariaDB in Dockercontainer - requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73065908/installing-mariadb-in-dockercontainer-requires-mariadb-connector-c-3-2-4-f) but doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pulling the latest MariaDB Connector/C from MariaDB managed to install with the latests python mariadb:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc wget
RUN wget https://dlm.mariadb.com/2678574/Connectors/c/connector-c-3.3.3/mariadb-connector-c-3.3.3-debian-bullseye-amd64.tar.gz -O - | tar -zxf - --strip-components=1 -C /usr
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install Flask Flask-SQLAlchemy flask-marshmallow marshmallow-sqlalchemy
RUN pip install mariadb
```

The libmariadb-dev packaged by Debian bulleye was too old.

libmariadb3 are client plugins, I'm not sure if you need those.