# How to use mariadb python connector in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, mariadb, mariadb-connector-c

I want to use the Python mariadb connector in a python container. Yet, until now, I've met only troubles and now I segfault when trying to pass arguments to my SQL queries.
here are my dockerfile and a script that highlight the problem.

```
FROM python:3.11-buster

RUN apt-get install gcc wget

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74429209/mariadb-in-docker-mariadb-connector-python-requires-mariadb-connector-c-3-2
RUN wget https://dlm.mariadb.com/2678579/Connectors/c/connector-c-3.3.3/mariadb-connector-c-3.3.3-debian-buster-amd64.tar.gz -O - | tar -zxf - --strip-components=1 -C /usr

WORKDIR /appli

RUN pip3 install pynetdicom>=2.0 mariadb==1.1.4

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "AEServer.py"]
```

```py
import mariadb

conn = mariadb.connect(user='myself', password='mypass', host=ip, database='db') # Successfully created connection
cursor = conn.cursor()
data = ('1.2.392', 'NAME^SURNAME^', 'BDAY', 'DX', 1) # Placeholder
insert_stmt = ("INSERT Examens VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %i, 'COMING')" % data)
segv_stmt = ("INSERT Examens VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'COMING')", data)
segv = "INSERT Examens VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'COMING')"

cursor.execute(insert_stmt) # GOOD
cursor.execute(segv, data) # Segmentation fault
```

First, I tried adding mariadb in my pip install in the dockerfile. It failed, because I didn't have the mariadb/c connector.

Then, I tried adding it by installing libmariadb3 and libmariadb-dev, according to this page of the documentation : https://mariadb.com/docs/ent/connect/programming-languages/c/install/ but I failed again, because the package fetched by the manager weren't up to date, so I had a version conflit when pip installing.

Then, I tried the following reference : [Mariadb in Docker: MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74429209/mariadb-in-docker-mariadb-connector-python-requires-mariadb-connector-c-3-2), to wget the connector and compiling it myself in the Dockerfile. I succeeded to create my container and I could create mariadb.coonnection and cursor so I thought it was over.

Finally when trying to use insert statement with placeholder (either '%s' or '?'), I am met with a segfault. I tried various associations of sources images (3.11:bullseye, 3.11:buster), connectors (version 3.3.3, 3.2.7) and mariadb (version 1.1.0, 1.1.2, 1.1.4), but all of them segfault.

What I want is a container with python3, my dependancy pynetdicom, and the ability to interract safely with a mariadb Database. A Dockerfile fulfilling the prevous prerequisites should be enough for me to move forward, but I also wish to know why things did happen this way.

Edit : Posted some credentials used in dev, removed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you installed a newer MariaDB Connector/C version, the preinstalled 3.1.13 version from 3.11-buster is still installed.

After installation of MariaDB Connector/C 3.3.3 you have 2 versions installed:

- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadb.so.3
- /usr/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so.3

Now when running your python script, it crashes in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadb.so.3.

To force Python to use the newer MariaDB Connector/C library just add

`ENV LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so` or `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/mariadb`

to your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is indeed the solution to use your env adding. Couldn't guess there were already a connector preinstalled in my image.

Comment: It's always a problem if you build with an include file which has different version than the library. Maybe it would be good to check version from include file and library during initialization of mariadb module and raise an exception if they don't match.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it should be checked during module initialization.