# Writes an error when I install mariadb via pip

Tags: python, c, mariadb, debian, connector

I'm trying to install Mariadb via pip and getting the response:

```
Using cached mariadb-1.1.6.tar.gz (83 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2:
command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpe130c69j_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp50cdrwxx
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-8atxmc4c/mariadb_aec03e4f55c344b1a0fbd3c10ca46541
Complete output (1 lines):
MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C \>= 3.3.1, found version 3.1.18
-

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/f4/b93c582407689432927959c452321eb50ff027e878b09506b5a070bcd3f0/mariadb-1.1.6.tar.gz#sha256=af17a7eb29d24e9ac00f323909c4ba0c47f643ee4b7b890a158cb855ec866454 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mariadb/) (requires-python:\>=3.7). Command errored out with exit status 2: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpe130c69j_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp50cdrwxx Check the logs for full command output.
```

Initially the error was bigger, but I installed the libmariadb-dev library
and now this is the error. As I understand it, I need to install a new version of the C connector, but how can I do this?

Comment: This probably more appropriate for [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [serverfault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: Which version of `libmariadb-dev`? If this is a debian based, you might find a newer version in the backports. You have basically 3 options: 1. install an older version of mariadb (I mean via pip) that can work with `3.1.18`. 2. install a newer version of libmariadb-dev by hand (you will have to compile it yourself). 3. Use anaconda/miniconda as it also installs the needed libraries.

Comment: Ok, I trying install an older version and this is work! Thx!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mariadb in Docker: MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.2.4, found version 3.1.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74429209/mariadb-in-docker-mariadb-connector-python-requires-mariadb-connector-c-3-2)